# Intercept back button on uinavigationcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

A form is pushed onto the view. The form has several required fields. Also the form needs to be validated. I want to intercept the back button's click to check if the fields have been filled in, and validate the form. How would I intercept the button's click, and make sure it doesn't pop to the previous screen?