# prevent UIBarButtonItem animation in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using a nice custom transition using a category following what I read here:

[Changing the UINavigationController animation style](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/12/31/Changing-the-UINavigationController-animation-style.html)

This is great, BUT when I hit the back button the back button animates sliding and fading to the right.

I do not want it to animate at all.  I see the property `popNavigationItemAnimated` but cannot seem to get this to work.

Anyone have a way to accomplish this?

Comment: For future reference: that's a method, not a property.

Comment: Do you care whether or not your back button looks like a typical back button with a left edge that points left like an arrow?

Comment: One way would be to subclass the UINavigationController and the popViewController function...

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908016/intercept-back-button-on-uinavigationcontroller